Proving an unbounded integral polyhedron has integral direction of unboundedness.
Suppose I have a rational polyhedron $P := \{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb R^n : A\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}^m, \mathbf{x} \geq \mathbf{0}^n\}$ defined by  some integer matrix $A \in \mathbb Z^{n\times m}$ that I know is equal to the convex hull of its integer points, i.e. it is an integral polyhedron.
NB: the convex hull of a set of vectors $X \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ is the smallest convex set of vectors containing $X$ i.e.
$$
    \text{conv.hull}(X) = \{\lambda_1 \mathbf{x}_1 + \dots +\lambda_t \mathbf{x}_t 
    : 
    t \geq 1; \mathbf{x}_1, \dots, \mathbf{x}_t \in X; 
    \lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_t \geq 0;
    \lambda_1 + \dots + \lambda_t = 1
    \}.
$$
Suppose I also happen to know that the set $\{\mathbf{c}^T\mathbf{x} : A\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}^n, \mathbf{x} \geq \mathbf{0}^n\}$ is unbounded from below, for some integer vector $\mathbf{c} \in \mathbb Z^n$.
Then I'm fairly certain its safe to say then that for any negative value $N$, there exists an integral vector $\mathbf{x}^* \in \mathbb Z^n$ such that $\mathbf x \geq \mathbf 0^n$, $A\mathbf{x}^* = \mathbf{0}^n$, and $\mathbf{c}^T\mathbf{x}^* \leq N$.
But I'm struggling to find a nice obvious argument why. For context I've been reading Schrijver "Theory of Linear and Integer Programming" and I can't see this result anywhere explicitly.
I feel like I need to rely on the fact that $P$ must have an integral direction of unboundedness $d$ given that it is an integral polyhedron, but a bit stuck on how to prove that or find a clearly stated result for it somewhere.
Any tips?

Notation detail : It would be better to replace $cx$ by $c^Tx$

@Jean Marie Fixed.

Wouldn’t this follow from the argument in this answer? https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2134897/715329

@Pranay not immediately as far as I can tell? That question appears to asking about the existence of at least one integer solution, whereas I need to show there are infinitely many along a particular direction of unboundedness

Say you found one positive integer solution such that $c^T x <0$, then (positively) scaling it gives other integer solutions that make this quantity more and more negative. What is the issue here?

@Pranay how would I prove there exists such a solution? The argument you linked tells me there is some integer solution to $Ax = 0, x\geq0$, but not necessarily that $c^Tx < 0$ for that solution, although I might be missing something.

Consider a positive real solution with $c^T x = b <0$. After appropriately scaling $x$, you can assume that $b$ is an integer. Then $x$ satisfies $Ax =0$ and $c^T x = b$. This is a linear system of equations with integer coefficients. Since it has a positive real solution, it must have a positive integer solution.

@Pranay thanks for your help with this, I'm getting there but I still don't quite see it. How do we know we can scale $x$ so that $b$ is an integer? What if our real solution gives $c^Tx = -\pi$ or something?

Multiply both sides by $1/\pi$ to get $-1$ on the RHS, which is an integer. Note that $x/\pi$ is still a positive real solution of $Ax=0$ if $x$ is a solution.

@Pranay Ahh okay I've got it now. Think I should be able to write out a proof now - thank you so much for the help!

Turning the comment thread into an answer:
Let $x \ge 0$ be a positive real solution of $Ax=0$ such that $c^Tx=b<0$. Define $x’=x/|b|$. Then, $x’$ is a positive real solution of the linear system $Ax=0$ and $c^Tx=-1$. Since all coefficients and constants are integers, there should be a positive integer solution (see this answer for a proof of this assertion: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2134897/715329).
Now given such an integer solution, scaling it by positive integers gives more positive integer solutions of $Ax=0$ such that $c^Tx$ is more and more negative, which is what we wanted to prove.
